# WPF, MVVM, ICommand, and repositories

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, repository

I have a WPF application that looks something like this:

[image]

The viewmodel wraps the model and exposes any attributes relevant to the view via INotifyChanged. The view is also bound to several ICommand objects that handle certain behavior triggered by the view. I have an external ICommand who's sole purpose is to save the model to a database.

Everything I've read indicates that neither the view or the viewmodel should have a reference to the repository. This is the reason for Command 3 which is outside of the viewmodel.

My question is twofold. First, is this a reasonable architecture, and second, what is a good way to get the model instance over to command 3 so it can be put in the repository?

Comment: How exactly are `Command 1` and `Command 2` IN the VM and `Command 3` is OUT of the VM? Aren't all commands implemented separately in their own classes and just 'added' to the VM as its properties? In this context, how is one command IN the VM and another OUT of the VM??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I, personally, see no problem with having the ViewModel have a reference to the repository.  Trying to avoid this will cause unnecessary complications.

In MVVM, the ViewModel is typically the "glue" layer that sits above your Model - and the Repository is part of the Model (it's part of the domain specific data/logic).  My [blog series on MVVM shows a good image](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/06/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-7-mvvm/) of how I personally think about this:

[image: MVVM Diagram]

Letting the VM work with the Repository directly by putting Command 3 into the VM would likely be cleaner than trying to separate it out.

Comment: I would just add a little bit to what Reed said: You could certainly decouple it somewhat by abstracting away the details of your repository if you wanted. But I agree, no reason to completely separate them the way that diagram shows.

Comment: @Tim Good point.  Abstracting away the repository details is very useful, but almost a separate issue (great for testability, etc).

Comment: I agree that it is kind of a separate issue, but I somewhat wonder if that sort of abstraction might have been the reason behind the OP hearing that he should decouple them. Just wanted to kind of answer the "well then why did [whoever] say that I should do it if I don't need to?" question before he asked it!

Comment: @Tim I suspect you may be right.  I find that a lot of times, when people talk about MVVM, they include a LOT of issues that aren't really MVVM.  Most of the "frameworks" include tons of code that's very good and useful, but really separate concerns to the core architectural pattern.  I think this makes life very confusing for people just coming to MVVM and trying to understand it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. Our repository is already abstracted into it's own class. It makes sense to me now why someone would say not to include repository "code" (sql statements etc) in the viewmodel, vs including a reference to an abstracted repository class.

Answer (score 0):

The View Model should communicate to the Business Layer (Domain Objects + Domain Services) and not the repository directly. Even further, this communication should be done via Commands.

So you have:

**View -> View Model -> Command -> Domain Object / Domain Service -> Repository**

Unless you are developing a really simple CRUD application ...